# Query with LVARCHAR performance in Informix DB

Tags: informix, dbeaver

In a maintenance project that it's working with IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.50.FC6 we have to improve the performance of some queries.
One of this queries to the Informix DB fetches a LVARCHAR datatype column and it takes too long.

I've also tried the same query with different programs (DbVisualizer, DBeaver) and I've found the same problem that in my aplication.
However, I've tried Server Studio and the same query is instant, so I gather that the database is not the problem.

I would like to know why Server Studio works so good. And how to copy its behaviour in my application, with JDBCTemplate.

Comment: Note that Informix 11.50 is not currently supported; you should be using at least 11.70 and preferably 12.10, with plans to move to 14.10 in the next year or so.

Comment: Resolving this will require a number of steps.  We'll need to establish which API the DbVisualizer, DBeaver and Server Studio systems use.  We may then need to determine exactly what requests are sent to the Informix server — the SQL statements and the data types.  Depending on what these find, there may be workarounds, or there may be bugs to be fixed, either in the programs or perhaps in the connectivity software (ODCB, OLEDB, JDBC, ESQL/C, … whatever).  If the problem is in the connectivity software, it won't be fixed in the versions used with 11.50 — they're no longer supported.